# Передача данных из HTML формы в адрес ссылки

Tags: html

Есть HTML форма (использую thymeleaf), нужно сделать так, чтобы те данные, которые ввели в форму(данные - цифры) и нажав на кнопку "отправить" перенаправляли на аналогичную страницу, но добавляли к ней значение из формы. Т.е. если форма отправляется со страницы по адресу /mobileshop/edit и в поле формы ввели 10, то осуществляется переход на страницу /mobileshop/edit/10   значение с параметрами с строке (?=10) не подходит

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: есть адрес страницы  /mobileshop/adminpage, на этой странице нужна форма для ввода и кнопка. Также есть страница на которую переходит пользователь после ввода данных в форму, это страница  /mobileshop/edit , но данные, которые ввел пользователь, должны продлевать  адрес страницы /mobileshop/edit/... т.е. вводя 10, переход будет на страницу /mobileshop/edit/10 , введя 14, на страницу /mobileshop/edit/14

Comment: @Виктор хорошо, если у вас в форме только цифры, а если там можно писать что угодно? Точно не знаю, но кажется нужно переписать формирование алиаса, чтобы он убирал ненужный вам "?=" и вставлял вместо этого "/".

Answer (score 0):

Свою проблему решил по другому -> переписал контроллер под запрос с параметрами (моя форма передавала введенные значения в виде параметров) и все работает как мне нужно.